# jQuery Datatable reload data - json to columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I have table that first time is server - side rendered. I want on some click event refresh data in table. 
Problem is how to "bind" specific json object propertie to specific column. I receive json object with array of objects where only some of properties are interesting me. 
I want 
Table column -- json object propertie 
 ID -- id 
 Name -- name + surname 
 Cooperation -- scCooperationCollection 
 Skills -- scSkillsCollection 
 Experience -- workExperience

HTML table: http://pastebin.com/b5yRWsGe 
JS reload table: http://pastebin.com/GzS8tpV6 
JSON example : http://pastebin.com/AyBSrSui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) or [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) options on how to bind source data to table columns or produce custom content for a cell.

You can access source data properties using dotted notation in `columns.data` or even join arrays with `[]` notation. For more complex data rendering like joining two fields, use `columns.render` instead.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
       url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/3x4ql',
       dataSrc: 'aaData'
    },
    columns: [
        { data: "id" },
        { 
            data: null, 
            render: function(data, type, full, meta){
               return full['name'] + ' ' + full['surname'];
            }
        },
        { data: "scCooperationCollection[,].scFields.name" },
        { data: "scSkillsCollection[,].scFields.name" },
        { data: "workExperience" }
    ]        
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7axwwcw/1/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate through the desired properties in returned json object and tie up same to your table something like below:

```
table.on( 'xhr', function () {
    var json = table.ajax.json();
    var obj = JSON.parse(json)
    var tableJson = {"ID":obj.aaData[0].id};
    console.log(json);
} );
```